# How to edit virtual field definitions in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a virtual field in QGIS. The values are updates depending another column with a concatenate CASE statements.

I would like to edit this statement but I cannot see it.

I have attempted to use the *field calculator* and choose the virtual field, but the statements just disappear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to your layer properties by double-clicking the layer (or *right-click > Properties*) and go to the **Fields** tab. You will see the list of fields available including virtual fields. The expressions are stored in the **Comment** column as shown in the image (the red circle highlights the *Expression Builder* tool which you can click to edit your expression):

[image: Field properties of layer]

---

*Note that virtual fields are stored in the project file (.qgs) and not in the shapefile itself.*